# Projection Matrix Causes Clip Cuttoff Problem

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to setup my renderer and I'm configuring the matrices. I currently have a View Matrix and a Projection Matrix which I then multiply and send to the shader(there's no need for model matrix since I'm just testing).

The problem is I just can't seem to get the projection matrix right. My model of a sphere appers cut in half in the center of the screen, I can move it around but once the Z value for the transform in the matrix goes beyond 1(Vulkan's max value for NDC) the model cuts off.

This is the code for the view matrix:

```c
ViewMatrix(3, 0) = CamPos.X;
ViewMatrix(3, 1) = -CamPos.Y;
ViewMatrix(3, 2) = CamPos.Z;
```

The numbers on the left are the rows and those on the right the columns. Matrices are row-major. And my renderer's coordinate system is left handed.

This is the code for the projection matrix:

```c
auto f = 1 / tan_half_fov;

_Matrix(0, 0) = f / _AspectRatio;
_Matrix(1, 1) = -f;
_Matrix(2, 2) = _Far / (_Near - _Far);
_Matrix(2, 3) = -1;
_Matrix(3, 2) = (_Near * _Far) / (_Near - _Far);
```

The matrix is just an identity matrix and the every frame it gets set those values. `tan_half_fov` is 0.41421356, since it's tan(45 deg / 2). `_Near` is 1, and `_Far` is 500.

The vertex shader:

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = inData.Pos * vec4(inPos, 1.0);
}
```

`inPos` is the vertex data input for vertex position and `inData.Pos` is the ViewProjection matrix.

The matrix multiplication code is working alright, I tested it. When sending to the shader just the view matrix the sphere appears all flat on the screen and moves around correctly. I am using Vulkan.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Set the near value to something smaller (but still positive). It will cut anything off if it goes closer to the camera, than 1 unit

Comment: @Bálint Setting the near value to 0.5 didn't solve it. The problem is, things (Vertices) seem to clip when they go beyond 1.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, you need to understand how a projection matrix works:

A projection matrix represents a frustum, shown in this image:

[image]

As you can see, it looks a bit like a pyramid with the cap cut off, or trapezium.

The near and far values tell the shader which fragments to draw, via a depth test.

Fragments, once translated to screen space, will be culled, if they have a z value of less than 0, or greater than 1.

Now let's look at "handed-ness":

[image]

OpenGL uses a right handed coordinate system, whilst Vulkan uses a left handed coordinate system, with the exception that the Y axis is flipped.

If your perspective transform maps a z value outwith the range of [0-1], then it will be culled, so check your perspective transform construction.

Comment: This is wrong, [Vulkan does not have Z point positive towards the viewer](http://anki3d.org/vulkan-coordinate-system/), it goes from [0, 1], pointing outwards, with *y flipped* being, -1 at the top, and 1.0 at the bottom. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036410/why-doesnt-vulkan-use-the-standard-cartesian-coordinate-system) as well

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I have edited my answer.